# How to send meeting invite on email in django form?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I would like to implement a form in Django, from where I can send a meeting invitation. For that, I have created a form where a user can enter the sender email, start date, and end time.

Now I want when users click on the submit button after entering email and time, then an email calendar should be sent to the sender mail through the Django admin panel.

[image: the Django admin panel]

Answer (score 0):

At first assign a string for the email id to store it . Assign two variables for date and time. Type a conditional statement that if the users clicks it send the mail to the mail id. But how to send the mail?.... Thsi can be done by a libray called smtplib.
https://realpython.com/python-send-email/
If the user clicks submit the statement becomes true, and the mail will be sent. I hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a save function in your model then while submit or save model field this email will send to customer email

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ctx = {"user": self.content, "email": self.email} // Here you can add what you want to send in email
        tpl = "meeting.html" // here is your email templates
        html_message = render_to_string(tpl, ctx)
        send_mail(
            subject="Thank you for joining us", // This is your subject
            message="",
            html_message=html_message,
            from_email="Meeeing <your email id>",
            recipient_list=[self.email], // customer email
        )
```